# Whats the rollover text on an image called?

Tags: images

You know, when you hold your mouse over an image for a while and that little text box comes up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is called a "tooltip"

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "tooltip".

You can get one over images on a web page by adding a title attribute. This is dependent on implemention in the browser, but it's pretty widely adopted

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnmVY.png" title="this is the tooltip"/>
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note, sometimes browsers display a tooltip based on the alt text (the value of the **alt** attribute); which is a standard for when a browser cannot display the image, the alt text is shown.

Answer (score 5):

It's called a [tooltip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip).

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate; he posted a few seconds before me. I don't really want to delete though; since I included a Wikipedia link.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for including the link. :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this in HTML?  If so it is the title attribute ie `<img src="x.jpg" title="tooltip"/>`

Answer (score 0):

**Correction:** A **tooltip** is when a balloon appears and gives the user a bit of information about a task they are about to perform, traditionally associated with an "i" icon or "?" a question mark icon. **Rollover** or **mouseover text** is the text that appears for HTML hyperlinked text and images and was originally created for browsers that may be unable to publish photos and gives users context to what is being shown without seeing the image.